# Experimentos en Google Play Developer Console

Tags: android, google-play

Estimados muy buenas tardes, lamentablemente tuvimos un inconveniente en la empresa y se ha extraviado la llave keystore para poder actualizar la aplicación que tenemos en producción, pero en fín, ya no tengo solución al respecto, lo que me queda es poder informar a los usuarios de nuestra aplicación (que son cerca de 10 mil) que la aplicación que actualmente están utilizando caducará en x fecha y a contar de alguna fecha determinada podrán descargar la nueva app, es posible estimado enviarles un mensaje a los usuarios activos de la app que ésta caducará?, veo en Google Play Developer Console  que existen unas opciones Fichas y experimentos, ¿es posible si me pueden orientar en el objetivo de experimentos y si esto ayuda con mi problemática?.

Saludos y muchas gracias.

Comment: Lo que se me ocurre es que les envíen la notificación por push.

Comment: No entiendo como quieren resolver el problema siempre con librerías, existe un concepto llamado Code Bloat, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_bloat lo cual se debe siempre evitar y hace la diferencia entre desarrolladores. No entiendo para que usar una librería si se puede resolver con solo algunas lineas de código. =P

Comment: Es por ese motivo que solicito que desarrolladores expertos me den alguna orientación respecto de un tema que desconozca, llevo muy poco tiempo desarrollando en android y es evidente que deben existir diferentes formas de hacer las cosas. Muchas gracias @Elenasys y me quedó clarito el tema de los códigos innecesarios, saludos. :)

Comment: Es una pena. A mi me ocurrió algo parecido planteado aquí : https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/64921/29967 sólo que pude recuperar mi keystore en una copia de Time Machine. Si el equipo donde se creó la app tenía algún sistema de backups puedes buscar la keystore como se explica en el enlace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En futuras versiones puedes integrar alguna librería cómo [AppUpdater](https://github.com/javiersantos/AppUpdater) o [Android-WVersionManager](https://github.com/winsontan520/Android-WVersionManager), para poder notificar que hay una versión de la app justo cuando el usuario abre la aplicación.

Comment: Muchas Gracias Webserveis, he estado revisando lo que me mencionaste y es muy buena idea para implementarlo desde ahora, tengo ciertas dudas con la librería pero abriré una nueva pregunta para resolverlas, saludos.

Comment: Es recomendable dar puntos a las respuestas a las que otorgamos el visto bueno @Rodrigo

Answer (score 1):

**Rodrigo, si tu aplicación no tiene implementado o no soporta notificaciones GCM o alguna forma de generar una notificación, toast ó dialogo, es imposible, ya que por seguridad no se puede inyectar una notificación.**

Regularmente este tipo de tareas se realizan al subir una aplicación, yo personalmente creo que es una tarea importante para evitar este tipo de situaciones.

Los datos para activar este mensaje regularmente se agregan dentro de un archivo de configuración que regularmente esta accesando la aplicación, puede ser .json,.xml,.plist, .rss, etc, de acuerdo a la configuración la aplicación  enviaría un aviso en un dialogo o notificación, puede sugerir redirigir a otra aplicación, o incluso mostrar un mensaje y no permitir la entrada a la misma aplicación.

Answer (score 0):

Desafortunadamente sin la llave no vas a poder hacer mucho ya que la acción que necesitas realizar es masiva y por seguridad no te lo va permitir.

Algo que podría funcionar es enviando un email a todos los usuarios de tu app, pero para esto tu app tendría que estar configurada para pedir permiso al usuario para recibir emails al momento de instalar, si tu app ya tiene ese permiso puede funcionar.

Checa este [link](https://www.quora.com/Can-Android-developer-send-out-mass-emails-to-app-users-1).