# ¿Se puede cambiar el package ID o bundle ID y haver un update a mi app en el google play store?

Tags: android, unity, google-developers-console

Tengo una duda sobre este tema ya que he leido en sitios que no puedo hacerlo y en otros que si.

Tengo una app publicada y activa en google play, he cambiado Admob con mi ID, me gustaria saber si puedo cambiar tambien el package ID o bundle ID y simplemente hacer un update a mi aplicacion despues de esto. ¿Se puede hacer o el package ID tiene que ser el mismo? no quiero crear una nueva app, la que esta ya esta publicada y solo me interesa un update.

¿Se puede hacer?

Comment: relacionada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64920/comet%C3%AD-un-grave-error-con-mi-app-android-perd%C3%AD-el-archivo-de-certificado-y-ahor

Comment: es un problema parecido al detallado ahi?

Answer (score 0):

**NO!**

> El [paquete de la aplicación](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html) (package id) es en realidad un identificador único de
>   la aplicación.

Si deseas cambiar el package ID, Google Play Store lo tomara como una aplicación diferente. **Si deseas realizar un update, tu .apk debe tener el mismo package ID.**

Comment: Ok, gracias me imaginaba que seria asi pero no lo tenia muy claro

Answer (score 0):

Bundle ID - identificador único para tu aplicación, no se puede cambiar. Una ID de aplicación representa una o más aplicaciones en el sistema de Apple Se compone de dos componentes, una ID de equipo y una cadena de búsqueda de ID de paquete .