# Error al actualizar apk anteriormente subido a Google Playstore

Tags: android, google-play-console

Quiero actualizar la apk que subi anteriormente en alpha y al momento de querer subirla me aparece este error, alguien me podria guiar en que es lo que debo hacer? por favor y muchas gracias por su ayuda
[image: Me aparece este error]

Comment: A mí me ocurrió exactamente lo mismo que a ti (creo), en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/64921/29967) explico cómo recuperar tu archivo de firma. Aunque lo hayas generado en otro dispositivo, se indica la ruta donde estaría ese precioso archivo de firmas que debes poner en un lugar seguro. Si era el equipo de otra persona contáctala lo antes posible para poder recuperar tu archivo.

Answer (score 1):

Si vas a subir un .apk a Google Play es estrictamente necesario que el .apk a subir sea firmado con la misma keystore con la que se se encuentra la actual aplicación, esto aplica aún en Alpha y Beta testing.

**Este keystore que generaste para firmar tu aplicación es sumamente importante guardarlo, realizar respaldo y evitar perderlo! porque no podrás subir actualizaciones firmadas de tu aplicación en caso de perderlo. Si lo pierdes te verás forzado a crear una nueva firma y subir otra aplicación diferente.**

Revisa esta respuesta:

[Recuperar llave publicación Aplicación Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8508/recuperar-llave-publicaci%C3%B3n-aplicaci%C3%B3n-android/8509#8509)

Comment: y en caso de que esto no sea asi? no tengo el equipo con el que firme la anterior

Comment: no necesitas el mismo equipo, necesitas el archivo con extensión .keystore que utilizaste originalmente para firmar tu aplicación que subiste a la tienda. Lo tienes?

Comment: no lo tengo, que puedo hacer? :(

Comment: ⤜(ʘ_ʘ)⤏ Lo siento es muy importante que lo guardes o respaldes, si no se tiene no podras subir .apk de actualización, tendrás que agregar una nueva aplicación.