# Recuperar clave de la Keystore para subir una APK a Google Play

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, apk

Actualmente estoy trabajando en algunas modificaciones para una aplicación de Android. La aplicación no la realicé yo, la realizó otra persona.

Nunca había trabajado en un desarrollo para Android, entonces me doy cuenta de que hay que generar un APK firmada. En la raíz del proyecto hay un archivo que se llama **NOMBRE_APP.keystore**.

Al tratar de generar el APK, se me piden otros campos que son: **Key store password, Key alias y Key password**. Esos datos no los tengo, ¿hay manera de obtenerlos, de Google Play Console por ejemplo? o en caso de no conseguirlos ya no se podrá actualizar la aplicación?

Comment: La clave del archivo .keystore no se puede recuperar, lamentablemente este se genera localmente en la PC y se firma según el desarrollador que la hizo, incluso desde la consola lo que puedes hacer es recuperar dicho certificado más no su clave a la hora de construir el apk. En el sitio en inglés ya alguien hizo esta pregunta y hay varias [respuestas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459719/android-i-lost-my-android-key-store-what-should-i-do)
que tal vez te sean útiles.

Comment: Aquí está la solución: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52590223/568179

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Es indispensable guardar en un lugar seguro la Keystore así como sus `Key store password` y `Key Password` y su con la cual se firman las aplicaciones que se suben a Google Play.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de lo contrario no podrás subir una actualización de tu aplicación!

Puedes revisar esta información en nuestro sitio:

[Recuperar llave publicación Aplicación Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8508/recuperar-llave-publicaci%C3%B3n-aplicaci%C3%B3n-android/8512#8512)

[Cometí un grave error con mi App Android: perdí el archivo de certificado y ahora no puedo subir actualizaciones a Play Store](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64920/comet%C3%AD-un-grave-error-con-mi-app-android-perd%C3%AD-el-archivo-de-certificado-y-ahor/79808#79808)

Si tienes la **Keystore pero no tienes el password, puedes intentar como opción**:
https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-keystore-password-recover/

---

> Actualmente estoy trabajando en algunas modificaciones para una
>   aplicación de Android. La aplicación no la realicé yo, la realizó otra
>   persona.

**La persona que realizó la aplicación debió dejar la Keystore con la que se firmo la aplicación así como los passwords.**

> Nunca había trabajado en un desarrollo para Android, entonces me doy
>   cuenta de que hay que generar un APK firmada. En la raíz del proyecto
>   hay un archivo que se llama NOMBRE_APP.keystore.

**Probablemente este es el Keystore con el que se firmo la aplicación ya que cuando creas un proyecto, no se crea un archivo Keystore automáticamente.
Cuando pruebas tu aplicación esta usa el Keystore de desarrollo, que no es para subir la aplicación a Google Play, este archivo esta úbicado en :**

```
C:\Users\<USUARIO>\.android\android.keystore
```

> Al tratar de generar el APK, se me piden otros campos que son: Key
>   store password, Key alias y Key password. Esos datos no los tengo,
>   ¿hay manera de obtenerlos, de Google Play Console por ejemplo? o en
>   caso de no conseguirlos ya no se podrá actualizar la aplicación?

**Si no los consigues, desgraciadamente no podrás realizar actualizaciones de la aplicación, tendrás que subir una nueva aplicación.**

Comment: Vaya, muchas gracias. Eso me temía, en fin, intentaré contactar al desarrollador que hizo la aplicación originalmente. Si no, no quedará de otra más que subir la aplicación como nueva.

Comment: @VicenteGutiérrez hay que tener cuidado con el Keystore, siempre tener respaldo, saludos Vicente!

Answer (score 0):

bueno investigue un poco si se puede recuperar tanto el password y el key alias

1. entra en android studio y pone su app en proyecto o project
2. despliegue la carpeta de gradle
3. hay una carpeta que tiene el numero de la versión de gradle que estas usando en mi caso es 7.0.2 si estas en un proyecto antiguo creo será 4.0.2 pero ubica la carpeta con el numero puede ser cualquiera
   4.despligue la carpeta que dice executionHistory en proyecto antiguo puede ser taskHistory
4. ubica el archivo que termine en bin
5. dale doble click para abrirlo en android studio o puedes abrirlo en un editor
6. hace ctrl + F y busca .keyAlias hasta que encuentras la tuya
7. hace lo mismo para el storePassword solo busca .storePassword
   si cuando estabas creado la llave ponías la encriptación de su contraseña entonces aparecerá encriptada
   espero que sea de buen ayuda porque gracias a eso recupere la contraseña y mi keyalias

Comment: En el caso de que este encriptada como haces para desencriptarla?