# ¿Se puede seguir subiendo una app a play store teniendo debug.keystore?

Tags: flutter, google-play, keystore

He realizado cambios en una app, la cual ya esta publicada en **play store**.

Al investigar, encuentro los archivos a guardar son el **`jks`** y el **`debug.keystore`** de los cuales en su momento solo respalde `debug.keystore`.

actualmente por diversas acciones erróneas se genero un nuevo archivo **`jks`** y al parecer igual se genero un nuevo `debug.keystore`.

**buscando en los respaldo encuentro el `debug.keystore` pero no el `jks`**
[aquí la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/64921) que menciona un poco sobre la importancia de guardar el `debug.keystore`

1. **¿Es posible seguir subiendo actualizaciones teniendo el `debug.keystore`?**
2. **Si se puede ¿que proceso debo realizar para poder seguir subiendo actualizaciones de la app?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, no es posible actualizar tu app si no tienes la llave que usaste para subirla.

Recomiendo que actualices la descripción del Play Store de tu aplicación original y pongas un enlace hacia la nueva app para que tus usuarios puedan migrar.

Luego de eso lo mejor es que eliminas la app vieja y continuas con la nueva, y mantén seguro la nueva key que usarás.

Para cuando subas tu nueva app te recomiendo usar el app signing by Google Play, esto te permite subir la key original para que está segura y no tengas problemas si en algún momento la pierdes.

Te dejo este link para que leas un poco más.
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en-GB

Comment: Ok.. ¿entonces el archivo a guardar y respaldar en todo momento, es el que se genera para **release** el `jks`?

Comment: así es, cuídalo como oro.

Comment: ahí actualicé mi respuesta para que puedas encontrar más info, pero lastimosamente si no usaste el app signing by google play, entonces no puedes subir updates porque ya perdiste la key original