# Android App Bundle informa de la clave es incorrecta

Tags: android

Estoy tratando de subir una app a Google Play.
**Es una app que descargue de GitHub y la personalice.**
Cuando intento subir el .aab da el siguiente error:
"Tu Android App Bundle está firmado con una clave incorrecta. Asegúrate de que se firme con la clave de firma adecuada y vuelve a intentarlo. Se espera que el App Bundle se firme con el certificado que contiene la huella digital

SHA1: 12:D0:60:8E:F4:27:7E:
, pero el que se usó para firmar el App Bundle que subiste contiene la huella digital
SHA1: 68:6F:BD:2

Cual podria ser el problema y que solucion potencial hay?

Comment: Hola. El mensaje de error te lo dice bastante claro: usas un archivo equivocado para firmar el App Bundle. Debes buscar el archivo que usaste para la primera firma y firmar el bundle con él. Y, te aconsejo que guardes ese archivo en un sitio seguro y bien identificado, porque si lo pierdes tu App se quedará como un fantasma en Google Play y tendrás que crear otra. [Revisa esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/64920/29967) para más detalles sobre el tema.

Comment: Hola! Gracias por tu respuesta.
Considerando que los archivos originales de la app los descargue de GitHub y yo solo los personalice , tu crees que existe la posibilidad de que necesite la clave ORIGINAL? Clave que obviamente solo tiene el que desarrollo la app y la subió a GitHub.
Quizá puedas orientarme al respecto.

Comment: Suponiendo que usaste ese código como base para crear una aplicación distinta y ahora quieres publicar tu aplicación en Play Store, no hay que darle más vueltas, firma la aplicación con tu propia clave y dale también un nombre distinto. Si es una copia exacta de la otra App es evidente que deberías evitar subir una App que no te pertenece.

Comment: La app que baje es una platilla sin valor alguno si no esta personalizada, cosa que hice yo. Mi recelo era que tuviera algún tipo de restricción para ser comercializada en Play Store.
Si es como me indicas es una muy buena noticia.
Gracias por tu tiempo, un saludo!

Comment: Es importante que cambies en el archivo gradle y consecuentemente en los nombres de paquete, el nombre de tu aplicación, poniendo tu propio nombre. Sí Play Store te dice que la firma no es la correcta significa que la App que usaste como plantilla existe en esa plataforma.

Answer (score 1):

Para subir a `Google Play` debes usar el `SHA1` del `Keystore` de producción, es decir, con el que subiste tu aplicación inicialmente.
Lo que indica el mensaje:

> "Tu Android App Bundle está firmado con una clave incorrecta.
> Asegúrate de que se firme con la clave de firma adecuada y vuelve a
> intentarlo. Se espera que el App Bundle se firme con el certificado
> que contiene la huella digital"

Es que **tratas de subir tu app firmada con otro certificado que no corresponde al que se usó inicialmente para firmar la primera versión de tu aplicación.**

Es muy importante también que tu aplicación tenga un `package name` (Id de aplicación) que no exista y que esté registrado por otro desarrollador.

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo. Un saludo!